# Why does Android Studio want me to use For Each instead of For Loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, android-studio, foreach

This question has been struggling me for time. Why sometimes does Android Studio want me to use For Each instead of For Loop, because when I use For Loop, I get a warning that I could be using for each (and with Alt+Enter it suggests me the autofix).

For example let's suppose we have this code

```
String a = "";
String[] array = {"A","B","C"};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    a += array[i];
    a += ",";
}
```

I get a warning

and this is the fix suggested by Android Studio

```
for (String anArray : array) {
        a += anArray;
        a += ",";
}
```

Is it more performant? There's a reason I should get a **warning** for actually using just for loop?

Or when it's better for loop or for each?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the book: Effective Java (2nd Edition) by Joshua Bloch

> The for-each loop, introduced in release 1.5, gets rid of the clutter and the opportunity for error by hiding the iterator or index
>   variable completely. The resulting idiom applies equally to
>   collections and arrays:

```
    // The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays
     for (Element e : elements) {
         doSomething(e);
     }
```

> When you see the colon (:), read it as “in.” Thus, the loop above reads as “for each element e in elements.” Note that there is no
>   performance penalty for using the for-each loop, even for arrays. In
>   fact, it may offer a slight performance advantage over an ordinary for
>   loop in some circumstances, as it computes the limit of the array
>   index only once. While you can do this by hand (Item 45), programmers
>   don’t always do so.

**Here is a comparison from http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops:**

```
static class Foo {
    int mSplat;
}

Foo[] mArray = ...

public void zero() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; ++i) {
        sum += mArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void one() {
    int sum = 0;
    Foo[] localArray = mArray;
    int len = localArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void two() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Foo a : mArray) {
        sum += a.mSplat;
    }
}
```

> `zero()` is slowest, because the JIT can't yet optimize away the cost of
>   getting the array length once for every iteration through the loop.
>
> `one()` is faster. It pulls everything out into local variables,
>   avoiding the lookups. Only the array length offers a performance
>   benefit.
>
> `two()` is fastest for devices without a JIT, and indistinguishable from
>   `one()` for devices with a JIT. It uses the enhanced for loop syntax
>   introduced in version 1.5 of the Java programming language.
>
> **So, you should use the enhanced for loop by default, but consider a
>   hand-written counted loop for performance-critical ArrayList
>   iteration.**

Answer (score 1):

It's just more readable when you just iterate without looking ahead or backward. Well, it's readable if you choose a good variable name (unlike `anArray` for a `String` :D). It's a bit safer too because if you were a really stupid programmer you could write `array[2 * i]` and throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Apart from this, I find it a bit exaggerated to ask you to refactor that... this is a common idiom in Java.